# Access Value From Modal Form In C# Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am using JQuery to Launch a modal pop-up on a linkbutton press event.  The user is inputting text and I want to capture that text in my C# syntax to store in Database.

The modal dialog can be launched up to 8 times to input a value for 8 different entries.  The issue that I have with my syntax is that it only retains the last input value, and not each previous one.

How would I go about capturing the value for each input?

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Additional</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p></p>
           <asp:Label ID="lblCurrentText" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrentText" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="btnUpdateModel">Update</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now pressing the update button will only update the view on the page.  It does not make a database update.  The database update occurs when a button press on the page occurs, and this was the syntax I attempted to use to achieve such result, but am only getting the last entry:

```
string bluegreenred = txtCurrentText.Text;
```

How can I have each entry saved in a C# variable for DB insert?

Comment: If you want to capture all 8 inputs on PostBack at once you have to use either 8 modals or store those 8 values with jQuery in a HidddenField as array data and process that. A third option would be to send and store the data using Ajax calls to a webservice. It would be much easier to store data after just one modal change.

Comment: @VDWWD - sorry for my ignorance here, but would the 8 HiddenField exist on my main form or the modal form that I have displaying?

Comment: The problem is you need to store the data for each Modal somewhere before you are sending it to the server. So yes you could use 8 hiddenfields or generate an array in a single one. But like I said it would be easier to save each modal change diretly with a PostBack.

Comment: @VDWWD - yikes, so no easy clean way to make this insert.  How delightful.  Thank you for the insight

Comment: Unfortunately no. Quickest and easiest for you is a PostBack per Modal change. But the user friendliest and best performing option would be an ajax call to save the changes.

Comment: @VDWWD - any tutorial or further guidance on how to do such with an ajax call as you suggest?  I have been googliing but not finding anything worthwhile